# Select dictionary from dictionares?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have problem with select dicionary from dictionares, 
my structure `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, object>>` 
i try `Select(x => x.Value) and SelectMany(x => x.Value)` but result is `IEnuerable<Dictionary<long, object>>` do you have any ideas, how can i select this dictionary?

Comment: it will easy if you provide input and expected output

Comment: You can select the value of the outer dictionary by providing a key into the indexer operator.: `outerDictionary[dictionaryKey]`

Comment: this is input ```Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, object>>``` , i want output ```Dictionary<long, object>```

Comment: could you please show us your actual code?

Comment: Rubber duck debugging and worked, ```.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.Value)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select returns an `IEnumerable`, so you should either do `.FirstOrDefault()` on the result, or use a method like `TryGetValue`

Answer (score 0):

> Select and SelectMany will result in `IEnumerable`

try with `SelectMany` and then convert to desired `Dictionary`

```
var result = dd.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```